# Bootstrap accordion remove panel on button click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

I am using Bootstrap accordion which is dynamically created based on select options from a select list option so for each option selected, I append an accordion panel to the existing accordion.

As well as being able to add panel, I want to be able to remove a panel.  I did think about having a close button but I'm unable to target the click event on the close button (span).

Here is a sample of what is output when I create the accordion

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="panel list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sm" data-parent="#menu">MESSAGES <span class="label label-info">5</span> <span class="fa fa-close pull-right"></span></a>
        <div id="sm" class="sublinks collapse">
            <div class="list-group-item">
                TEST1
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
                TEST2
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
                TEST3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought clicking this element `<span class="fa fa-close pull-right">` would cause an event to fire but it never does. It just opens/closes the panel as the default behaviour.

I did think about trying to use Jquery to deal with the accordion but that seems like a lot of extra effort.

Do i need to put my close button somewhere else or am I missing anything that can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fa-close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
})
```

Comment: please add informations why this snippet solves the issue

Comment: As the close button is on panel; it will start propagation behavior of accordian after clicking anywhere on panel.
We need to remove complete panel on clicking of close button, which is 2nd parent of that button.
So we are targetting it as .parent().parent() and then .remove()
Also if you just want to stop accordion propogation simply use

$('.fa-close').click(function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});

Comment: Relying on the exact node traversal path is risky ( `.parent().parent()…` ) because the code will probably break whenever changes are made to the markup.

Comment: please use the `edit` function for adding informations to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use what is is called [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).
A single click event listener/handler is attached to a common ancestor (`div#menu` in this case).

Using this technique, you normally have to test the original clicked element with the help of the event object `event.target` property to know if any action applies. jQuery ease this process by making `on()` function accept a 2nd argument (being a selector matching the target) right before the handler function. You then only have to implement the actual action: the associated `.panel` removal in this case.

Main pros are that dynamically added `.panels` (after event registration) will also trigger the "removal" handler. Only a single function is kept in memory.

You will also have to put the `span.fa-close` outside the anchor and use a bit of CSS to prevent the accordion collapse behavior to interfere with the close action.

**Example:**

```js
$(function(){
    // When a click happens in the menu and has been triggered
    // by an element having the '.fa-close' applied to it.
    $('#menu').on('click', '.fa-close', function(e){
       // Remove the associated '.panel' element
       $(this).closest('.panel').remove();
    });
});
```

```css
#menu .panel{position: relative}
#menu .fa-close{position: absolute; right:15px; top:15px; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="menu">
    <div class="panel list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sm1" data-parent="#menu">
            MESSAGES <span class="label label-info">5</span>
        </a>
        <div id="sm1" class="sublinks collapse">
            <div class="list-group-item">
                TEST1
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
                TEST2
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
                TEST3
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="fa fa-close pull-right" title="Remove this entry"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="panel list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sm2" data-parent="#menu">
          MESSAGES <span class="label label-info">3</span>
        </a>
        <div id="sm2" class="sublinks collapse">
            <div class="list-group-item">
                TEST4
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
                TEST5
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
                TEST6
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="fa fa-close pull-right"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise you will have to attach a click *event handler* on each `span`, and do so each time a new panel is added to the DOM.